# Merge table results into columns (pivot/crosstab?)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have ~30 tables which gets "streamed" data from an external system. I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve the tables last known values for a specific point in time and present that in a convenient way.

Let's describe the table layout:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
    id1             INT NOT NULL,
    id2             TEXT NOT NULL,
    update_time     TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
    val             NUMERIC NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2, update_time)
)
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (
    id1             INT NOT NULL,
    id2             TEXT NOT NULL,
    update_time     TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
    val             INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2, update_time)
)
;

--...tableN(


INSERT INTO table1(id1, id2, update_time, val) VALUES (1, 'ident 1', '2004-10-19 09:00:00', 1.23);
INSERT INTO table1(id1, id2, update_time, val) VALUES (1, 'ident 1', '2004-10-19 10:05:00', 1.25);

INSERT INTO table2(id1, id2, update_time, val) VALUES (1, 'ident 1', '2004-10-19 10:03:00', 23);
INSERT INTO table2(id1, id2, update_time, val) VALUES (1, 'ident 1', '2004-10-19 10:03:30', null);
```

Now the optimal way for me to have the data presented would be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM lastknownvalues
WHERE id1 = 1
AND id2 = 'ident 1'
AND time = '2004-10-19 10:04:00'
```

Which would return a single row:

```
time                     id1    id2     table1    table2
'2004-10-19 10:04:00'    1      ident1  1.23      null
```

At 10:04:00 the last known value in table1 was 1.23 (the update to 1.25 was made later)
table2 got updated to null at 10:03:30, so should be null in the result.
Note that the data types for val is different in the tables.

I've been struggeling with pivot/crosstab since that looks close enough to the functionality I'm looking for but I am unable to figure out how to do it, can you figure it out? :)

### A follow up question:

What if I would like to retrieve all values within an interval, to get all combined information between 2 timestamps?
For example if selecting with start_timestamp 2004-10-19 09:00:00 and end_timestamp 2004-10-19 10:04:00 get a result like:

```
time                     id1    id2     table1    table2
'2004-10-19 09:00:00'    1      ident1  1.23      null
'2004-10-19 10:03:00'    1      ident1  1.23      23
'2004-10-19 10:03:30'    1      ident1  1.23      null
```

Possible..? (Note that I got data in ~30 tables to combine with the above desired output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the most recent timestamp first use the comparison operator to rule out future timestamps. Next, order by smallest interval by subtracting possible timestamp candidates from your desired timestamp. To get just the most recent result, limit 1.

To get the table2 `val` column to display with the table1 columns, you just need to run the same code for table2 within a subquery.

```
SELECT update_time AS time, id1, id2, val, (
  SELECT val from table2 
  WHERE '2004-10-19 10:04:00' >= update_time
  ORDER BY '2004-10-19 10:04:00' - update_time
  LIMIT 1
)
FROM table1 WHERE '2004-10-19 10:04:00' >= update_time
ORDER BY '2004-10-19 10:04:00' - update_time
LIMIT 1;
```