# Merge table results into columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

(This is a follow up question to [Merge table results into columns (pivot/crosstab?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234149/merge-table-results-into-columns-pivot-crosstab) )

I have ~30 tables which gets "streamed" data from an external system. I'm trying to figure out how to combine the data collected into a single query result.

Let's describe the table layout:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
    id1             INT NOT NULL,
    id2             TEXT NOT NULL,
    update_time     TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
    val             NUMERIC NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2, update_time)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (
    id1             INT NOT NULL,
    id2             TEXT NOT NULL,
    update_time     TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
    val             INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2, update_time)
);

--...tableN(


INSERT INTO table1(id1, id2, update_time, val) VALUES (1, 'ident 1', '2004-10-19 09:00:00', 1.23);
INSERT INTO table1(id1, id2, update_time, val) VALUES (1, 'ident 1', '2004-10-19 10:05:00', 1.25);

INSERT INTO table2(id1, id2, update_time, val) VALUES (1, 'ident 1', '2004-10-19 10:03:00', 23);
INSERT INTO table2(id1, id2, update_time, val) VALUES (1, 'ident 1', '2004-10-19 10:03:30', null);
INSERT INTO table2(id1, id2, update_time, val) VALUES (1, 'ident 1', '2004-10-19 10:05:00', 42);
```

Is it possible to combine all the "known data at a specific time" from all tables in a single query? Something like:

```
SELECT update_time, t1_val, t2_val
FROM combined_output
WHERE start_time = '2004-10-19 08:00:00'
AND end_time = '2004-10-19 12:00:00'
```

Which would give the result:

```
time                       t1_val    t2_val
'2004-10-19 09:00:00'      1.23      null
'2004-10-19 10:03:00'      1.23      23
'2004-10-19 10:03:30'      1.23      null
'2004-10-19 10:05:00'      1.25      42
```

A little explanation:

At 09:00:00 we knew table1 had a value of 1.23. No value was present in table2 so value from that should be null.

At 10:03:00 table2 got 23 added. The value 1.23 in table1 is still the last known value from table1, so that should still be present in the output.

10:03:30 as above.

10:05:00 both table1 and table2 got new values but the query returns only a single row in the output, containing both new values in t1_val and t2_val.

It's actually not critical to filter away possible values before the requested time range. If table2 would have had a value set at 08:59:00 it's no harm if that value gets shown in t2_val at the first row in the example even if it's not optimal.

(Note that I have ~30 tables to combined data from, so looking for a solution which can be expanded to many tables. Changing the table layout is not possible. High performance is not required.)

Comment: you can use `full join` but the query would look awkward with so many tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a solution combining a function with select.

First I create a function which returns the known values for a specific time:

```
DROP FUNCTION last_known_values(timestamp without time zone,integer,text);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.last_known_values(
    IN time_to_check timestamp without time zone,
    IN id1 integer,
    IN id2 text)
  RETURNS TABLE(checked_time timestamp without time zone, id1 integer, id2 text, t1_val numeric, t2_val int) AS
$BODY$

SELECT time_to_check AS time, id1, id2,
(
  SELECT table1.val AS t1_val from table1
  WHERE $1 >= table1.update_time
  AND table1.id1 = $2
  AND table1.id2 = $3
  ORDER BY table1.update_time DESC
  LIMIT 1
),
(
  SELECT table2.val AS t2_val from table2
  WHERE $1 >= table2.update_time
  AND table2.id1 = $2
  AND table2.id2 = $3
  ORDER BY table2.update_time DESC
  LIMIT 1
)

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

Then I use this function with any timestamp range, filtering so only timestamps present in table1 or table2 (..tableN) is fetched:

```
SELECT last_known_values.* FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT update_time 
    FROM (
        SELECT update_time 
        FROM table1
        WHERE update_time BETWEEN '2004-10-19 08:00:00' AND '2004-10-19 12:00:00'
        AND table1.id1 = 1
        AND table1.id2 = 'ident 1'

        UNION
        SELECT update_time 
        FROM table2
        WHERE update_time BETWEEN '2004-10-19 08:00:00' AND '2004-10-19 12:00:00'
        AND table2.id1 = 1
        AND table2.id2 = 'ident 1'
    ) t
    ORDER BY update_time ASC 
) times_to_fetch, last_known_values(times_to_fetch.update_time, 1, 'ident 1'::text);
```

Gives the result:

```
"2004-10-19 09:00:00"    1    "ident 1"    1.23    (null)
"2004-10-19 10:03:00"    1    "ident 1"    1.23    23
"2004-10-19 10:03:30"    1    "ident 1"    1.23    (null)
"2004-10-19 10:05:00"    1    "ident 1"    1.25    42
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating a view which combines all the data then you can query the view as needed.

Create view:

```
create view combined_output as select * from table1 union all 
                               select * from table2 union all 
                               ...
                               select * from tableN;
```

Run query:

```
SELECT update_time, t1_val, t2_val
FROM combined_output
WHERE update_time between '2004-10-19 08:00:00' and '2004-10-19 12:00:00'
```

*Caveat: I have not tried any of this.*

Comment: Using a union would place all values in the same column. I'm looking for some way to get the different tables into separate columns, but with the "last known values" merged into a single row.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are linked with a Foreign key it could be done with a join statement.
From what it looks like from your tables there is no FK so use a Union. This will provide you with a lot of data however.

Comment: As commented above, a Union will merge the data from the different tables into a single column, not separate as requested.